# How to transfer onclick with a jsp variable and direct to other page

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, sql-update

Do anyone know how to transfer variable from button to other page.
I am creating a update and delete site. Database query all data, and there is a edit button, if i press edit, it will direct to the second site. This site will show which data information for you to update.

source code as below. I used below source code, when i enter edit, will will not direct to the page(edit_delete.jsp) 
Can any one plem me, whay is wrong with the code
Please see the bold in the source code that i mark, this might be a problem.

-----------------------------------------source code-----------------------------------------------------------

```
<script language="javascript">
function editRecord(no){
var f=document.form1;
  alert(no);  
f.method="post";
**f.action='edit_delete.jsp?id='+no;**
f.submit();
}
</script>

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=big5");
     stmt=con.prepareStatement("select id, no, name, class, from test");
     rs = stmt.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()) {
     int test = rs.getInt("no");
      out.print("<tr><td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("id"));
      out.print("</td><td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("no"));
      out.print("</td><td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("name"));
      out.print("</td><td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("class"));
     out.print("</td><td>");
     out.print("</td><td>");

      **out.println("<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick='editRecord('rs.getInt('no'))'>");**

      out.print("</td></tr>");



    }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to avoid *Scriplet* instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

[SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) is designed for accessing databases for quick prototyping and simple applications.

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
...

<sql:setDataSource var="webappDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=big5"
    user="root" password="" />

<sql:query dataSource="${webappDataSource}" 
            sql="select id, no, name, class, from test" var="result" />

<table width="100%" border="1">
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td>${row.no}</td>
            <td>${row.id}</td>
            <td>${row.no}</td>
            <td>${row.name}</td>
            <td>${row.class}</td>
            <td><input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick='editRecord(${row.no})' /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

You can try with [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) instead of form submit as it's simple get request and value is passed as query string in the URL.

For e.g.

```
<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick='window.open("edit_delete.jsp?id=${row.no}");'/>
```

Comment: any more other code. what if i want to used with java script, is there no way to solve this

Comment: Yes you can do it. Just enclose the button inside the form and simply call `form.submit` on it to pass the value as post request rather than get request.

Comment: any example.if i used form.sumbit i am not able to send value